# Analysis of sorting Algorithm with probably wrong comparator?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, machine-learning, probability, quicksort

**It is an interesting question from an Interview, I failed it.**

An array has **n** different elements [A1 .. A2 .... An]（random order）.

We have a comparator C, ***but it has a probability p to return correct results.***

Now we use C to implement sorting algorithm (any kind, bubble, quick etc..)

After sorting we have [Ai1, Ai2, ..., Ain] **(It could be wrong)**。

Now given a number **m** (m < n), the question is as follows:

1. What is Expectation of size ***S*** of Intersection between {A1, A2, ...， Am} and {Ai1, Ai2, ..., Aim}, in other words, **what is E[S]**?
2. Any relationship **among m, n and p** ?
3. If we use different sorting algorithm, **how will E[S] change** ?

My idea is as follows:

1. When m=n, E[S] = n, **surely**
2. When m=n-1, E[S] = n-1+P(An in Ain)

I dont know how to complete the answer but I thought it could be solved through induction.. **Any simulation methods would also be fine I think.**

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, maybe try [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Is the operator deterministic ? E.g for a and b and  `a<b` always returns the same answer. Which is correct with probability p, or maybe for each query `a<b` answer could be different (true or false), but p out of all answers will be correct ?

Comment: The result depends strongly on the sorting algorithm. If p < 1/2 then by increasing the running time of the algorithm you can increase the correctness of the sorting arbitrarily (by just repeating each comparison sufficiently many times). Wasn't the question more precise ?

Comment: @kkamilpl I believe that the comparator is correct with probability p, so, both sides (> or <) are correct with probability p.

Comment: @vib Yes, it will depend on sorting algorithm chosen, so we may choose bubble sort and merge sort as first attempt.

Comment: @Skyfall I have put this question over the other 2 sites.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, if A1,A2,...,An are in random order (as stated in the question), then all that sorting and probability of correctness of Comparator C does not really matter. The question is then reduced to the expectation of the length of intersection of two random subsets, each of size m, of {A1,...,An}.

The probability that S is k is then `(m k)*((n-m) (n-k))/(n m)`, where `(a b)` shall denote "a over b", the number of possibilities chosing `b` elements from `a` elements. (Because for the second subset we have to choose `k` elements out of the first subset and `m-k` elements from the rest.)

E[S] is then the `sum(0 <= k <= m) k*(m k)*((n-m) (n-k))/(n m)`, which reduces to `m/(n m) * sum(0 <= k <= m) ((m-1) (k-1))*((n-m) (n-k))`. This sum is a basic (well-known) binomial identity giving `((n-1) (m-1))`, so finally we get `m/(n m) * ((n-1) (m-1))` = `m^2/n`.

Comment: the probability does matter right ? there is still a certain probability of correct sorting.

Comment: I do not see how the probability p would matter. As I understand it A1,...,An are in random order. After "sorting" they are in a different order which is not related to the start order but only depends on the Comparator C (and maybe also the sorting algorithm). Things would be different if Ai1,...,Ain would be compared to the correct order. But Ai1,...,Ain is compared to a random start order.

Comment: Another way to view it: yes, the comparator's probability p influences the resulting order Ai1,...,Ain. But p does not influence the probabilities P(S=k) needed to compute E[S]. This is trivial when the comparator is deterministic, because then Ai1,...,Ain does not depend on the initial order A1,...,An (and also not on the sorting algorithm) and hence the two subsets are independent. If the comparator is not deterministic, then the resulting order depends on the intial order (and the algorithm), but I still think that e.g. P(A1=Ai1) = 1/n, i.e. independent of p.

Comment: Right : are we really comparing to the initial random array ? I thought that we were comparing to the correctly sorted array, but @coproc is right, this is not what the question currently says. But then the question is not very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer for modified question:

- Let's assume that Ai1,...,Aim is not intersected with the initial (random) array start, but with the first m values of the correctly sorted array Aj1,...,Ajn. (which seems to be more interesting)
- Let us further assume that the comparator C is non-deterministic.
- And for simplicity we assume all array elements are different and n=2^N.

Now the partial answer here is at first restricted to

- m=1
- sorting-algorith=merge sort

Aj1 is the smallest element. In merge sort each element is compared ld(n)=N times. The smallest element is sorted to the first position if and only if it turns out smaller in each of its ld(n)=N comparisons. So the probability P(Ai1=Aj1) = p^N, which equals for m=1 the requested E[S]. So we get

```
E[S] = p^ld(n)
```

And here is a partial answer for

- m=1
- sorting-algorith=bubble sort with getting the smallest elements in place first

If the smallest element is on position k at the beginning (Ak=Aj1), then it takes max(k-1,1) correct comparisons to bring Ak to the front (Ak=Ai1). Since all n start positions are equally probable we get

```
E[S] = P(Ai1=Aj1) = 
     = P(Ai1=Aj1|Aj1=A1)*P(Aj1=A1) + ... + P(Ai1=Aj1|Aj1=An)*P(Aj1=An) =
     = 1/n (p + p + p^2 + ... + p^(n-1)) = 1/n ((1-p^(n-1))/(1-p)+p-1) =
     = (2p - p^2 - p^(n-1)) / (n(1-p))
```

Good luck for the general case!